# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREASE PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, navicat

In my Navicat Premium:

I run the below code in Query Editor:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    empName VARCAHR(20),
    deptName VARCAHR(20)  
);
```

But I get the error:

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREASE PRIMARY KEY,
>       empName VARCAHR(20),
>       deptName VARCAHR(20)
>   )' at line 2

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: It is AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error cause it is `AUTO_INCREMENT` not `AUTO_INCREASE`
Change this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    empName VARCHAR(20),
    deptName VARCHAR(20)  
);
```

You can also create table and involve primary key second way

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    empName VARCHAR(20),
    deptName VARCHAR(20),PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    empName VARCHAR(20),
    deptName VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE MyStudents
(
   id    INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Comment: Please explain why you think using `UNSIGNED` is better. Why is your tablename `MyStudents`? Why should `name` be `NOT NULL`? And can you format your SQL in a codeblock, please?